# eclipse command in Play framework

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt

In a play application I found that "eclipse" command works by default without adding "sbt eclipse" plugin in the plugins.sbt file. However in case of Sbt this works only if this plugin definition is added. 
I was just wondering if Play is a wrapper over SBT with additional features available by default?

Comment: I think so, in their [github repo](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/02e05755753407bc238da6f57f551fa455d820cb/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/PlayEclipse.scala) and [here](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/02e05755753407bc238da6f57f551fa455d820cb/framework/project/Dependencies.scala#L159)

Comment: `play` is only a script, which internally uses `sbt` only

Comment: Which version of playframework are you asking for? Your question is tagged for both version, but playframework 1 doesn't use sbt explicitly.

Comment: I use the play framework version 2.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, Play is an sbt plugin. You can read about it in the documentation: [Create a new application without Activator](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/NewApplication#Create-a-new-application-without-Activator)

You can defined the eclipse plugin globally.

Settings can be placed here: **`~/.sbt/0.13/eclipseSettings.sbt`**

```
EclipseKeys.eclipseOutput := Some(".target")
```

Plugins can be placed here: **`~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/eclipse.sbt`**

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.5.0")
```

Activator itself is also built upon sbt: [Typesafe Activator, What is it?](https://typesafe.com/blog/typesafe-activator-what-is-it)